# Strategy to defeat final boss in Advance Wars 1

Tags: advance-wars

Does anybody have any good suggeestions for winning the final battle in Advance Wars 1?

I continually am getting creamed by meteor strikes and the final boss' ginormous army.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: maaaaaan, I remember that mission. I never beat that game because of it :<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I loved playing this game. Anyway, I forgot what the last mission was about so here's a tip from gamefaqs:

"In this Mission you'll want to control the Air, if you can achieve Air 
Superiority, or at least keep Sturm grounded, you shouldn't have any surprises 
to expect.  Another important thing to note is, that Sturm's troops have a high 
attack bonus, but they have a Defense deduction, so always make sure you attack 
him, never stay in defensive mode.  Always attack, attack, ATTACK! And you 
should win this mission."

you can read more here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/gba/471043-advance-wars/faqs/23377

or you could read the other walkthroughs there. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I found the strategy of just holding him behind the river and just building up an army way bigger than his worked perfectly for me.  Its not going to get you the best rating but you will win.  He cant build air units so once you take those out you are set to dominate the air.  I also let Andy capture most of the cities on your side of the map and feed all the incoming money to him.